# Pop Up Menu onclick BottomBar Button Windows 8 Metro App

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to have a popup menu once I click bottom bar button in windows 8 app, and pop up menu needs to be a multi-select, so that user can select multiple options and based on that I will need to refresh main screen. I need to implement this using Html and JavaScript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option is probably to show a `Flyout` control from an `AppBar` button.  The Flyout will let you compose the form you need (within [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465341.aspx)), but something like a `ListView` with multiple select enabled might be what you're looking for.

See the [HTML Flyout Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Flyout-sample-258757b3) to get started (scenario 6 shows a Flyout from the AppBar).

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I am able to create a flyout and the I am intending to do the same as in the link [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211726.aspx

Here I have added "multiple" option in the "select" and I am able to select more than one options but How should I retrieve the selected ones in .js file. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

the better option will be using SettingsFlyout

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout" 
         aria-label="App Settings Flyout" 
         data-win-options="{settingsCommandId:'defaults',width:'wide'}">
```

make your custom html layout and then call it on button click event

```
WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.showSettings(ID,Path );
```

you will find the references here:
[WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701253.aspx)

sample application : [App settings sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/app-settings-sample-1f762f49)